# How can the man get across the river with the two animals and the cabbage?

Tags: logical-deduction, river-crossing

> A man has a wolf, a goat, and a cabbage. He must cross a river with the two animals and the cabbage. There is a small rowing boat, in which he can take only one thing with him at a time. If, however, the wolf and the goat are left alone, the wolf will eat the goat. If the goat and the cabbage are left alone, the goat will eat the cabbage.
>
> How can the man get across the river with the two animals and the cabbage?

Source: http://www.puzzle.dse.nl/logical/index_us.html#wolf_goat_cabbage

Comment: Referenced in xkcd: http://xkcd.com/589/

Comment: @Andy [I was thinking of this one](http://xkcd.com/1134/)

Comment: @MartinBüttner: yep, that one too.

Answer (score 4):

> [This is a classic.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox,_goose_and_bag_of_beans_puzzle) I'm surprised it hasn't been asked before.
>  
>  **Take the goat.** This leaves the wolf and the cabbage which is fine.
>  **Return alone.**
>  **Take the cabbage.** (To the goat.)
>  **Return with the goat.** So it can't eat the cabbage.
>  **Take the wolf.** So it can't eat the goat.
>  **Return alone.** Again leaving the wolf with the cabbage.
>  **Take the goat.**
>  
>  Alternatively, you can swap the steps of taking the wolf and the cabbage.